# How to copy a button in iOS using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c

To copy a button, this has been working fine:

```
   NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: btn];
   UIButton *newButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
```

However since iOS12, this has been deprecated. But using the suggested method, causes the newButton to be nil. What am I doing wrong or indeed is there an alternative way to copy a UIButton. Full code:

```
// Init originalBtnsArray and
originalBtnsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Populate originalBtnsArray
for (UIButton *btn in btnsReferencesArray){
    // Below works but is now deprecated as of iOS 12
    //NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: btn];
    //UIButton *newButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:btn requiringSecureCoding:NO error:&error];

    NSError* unArchiveError = nil;
    UIButton *newButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[UIButton class] fromData:archivedData error:&unArchiveError];

    // newButton is nil, which is suboptimal
    [originalBtnsArray addObject:newButton];
}
```

Comment: And what's the value of `unArchiveError`?

Comment: '(null)' is the rather unhelpful value of unArchiveError.

Comment: That's an unusual usage of `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Archivers should be used to store/load data, not UI elements. Try instead storing the details that you want to configure the button with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now:

```
UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
newButton.frame = btn.frame;
[originalBtnsArray addObject:newButton];
```